# Access is denied. You'll need to provide administrator permission to perform this task

Tags: windows, windows-7

I accidently deleted all my data on D: drive and recovered the data using a recovery software but this time when i copy, paste or  delete something it says  'Destination folder access denied.  You'll need administrator permission to perform this task' with a 'continue' option [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VygY.png)
. So  how can i get rid  of  this problem ? My android studio project was in that drive and it is showing the error 'Access is denied' while i am accessing that project  in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

try (in an elevated shell)  to run
`takeown /R /F D:\`

for analysis of configured permissions, use `icacls`

Comment: I have tried the ownership of the  drive but it 's not working  please look at the screenshot link .